# calling a file move depending on the time of day file was created

Tags: c#, regex, file, move

after I parse through the name I would want to move the file according to the name which will vary from different time of the day. please some examples Thank you

```
string name = "reportONE14073012300000";
var match = Regex.Match(name, @"(?i)[a-z]+(\d{14})");
if(match.Success)
{
    DateTimedt=DateTime.ParseExactmatch.Groups1].Value,"yyMMddHHmmssff",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    string path = string.Format(@"A:\Report\{0}\ONE\{1}\{2}\{3}\{4}",
    dt.ToString("yyyy"),
    dt.ToString("MMMM"),
    dt.ToString("dd"),
    dt.ToString("HH00"),
    dt.ToString("mm00"));

}
```

Comment: `DateTimedt` should be `DateTime dt`

Comment: how would I call the move file to the folders with matching time stamps

Answer (score 0):

Use:
using System;
using System.IO;

```
Datetime dt = File.GetCreationTimeUtc("pathtofile");
```

to get the Timestamp

and use

```
File.Move(Source,Destination);
```

to move the file.